# How to set the value of dimmer element Tizen Wearable Web

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

How to set the value of dimmer element properly?
I  have these files. It's a basic structure from example.

**index.html**

```
    <div class="ui-page" id="dimmer-page">
        <div class="ui-content dimmer-content">
            <div class="ui-dimmer" id="dimmer"></div>
            <input id="slider" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100">
        </div>
        <script src="js/dimmer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/set_dimmer.js"></script>
    </div>
```

**dimmer.js**

```
/* global tau */
(function () {
    var page = document.getElementById("dimmer-page"),
        elSlider = document.getElementById("slider"),
        elDimmer = document.getElementById("dimmer"),
        dimmer,
        slider,
        pageBeforeShowHandler,
        pageHideHandler;

    pageBeforeShowHandler = function () {
        slider = tau.widget.Slider(elSlider);
        dimmer = tau.widget.Dimmer(elDimmer);
        elSlider.addEventListener("change", onInput, false);
    };

    function onInput(event) {
        var newVal = parseInt(event.target.value),
            convertedVal;

        dimmer.value(newVal);
    }

    pageHideHandler = function () {
        slider.destroy();
        dimmer.destroy();
    };
    
    page.addEventListener("pagebeforeshow", pageBeforeShowHandler);
    page.addEventListener("pagehide", pageHideHandler);
}());
```

I have mqtt broker that sends me value which I want to show in this dimmer.
I'v added this file.

**set_dimmer.js**

```
function setDimmerValue(value) {
    var dimmerElement,
        dimmer;
    
    dimmerElement = document.getElementById("dimmer");
    dimmer = tau.widget.Dimmer(dimmerElement);
    dimmer.value(value);
    
}
```

And when I get another value from mqtt I call this function. It shows me the proper value in percents, the brightness of background is proper, but the slider shows its default value, so I want it to work correct. When I leave this page and come back again it shows me the default value, but I want to show the last value I`v set.

Answer (score 0):

Above code presents connection of two widgets Slider + Dimmer.
Dimmer only show value as level of element brightness.
Slider has bound touch control. Method `onInput` changes dimmer value on the slider change.

So, if you want set value properly you should set Slider value.

```
function setValue(value) {
    var sliderElement = document.getElementById("slider"),
        slider;
    
    slider = tau.widget.Slider(sliderElement); // or tau.engine.getBinding(sliderElement)
    slider.value(value);
    
}
```